# PopOver and UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class odd behavior

Tags: ios, segue

Based on a uitableviewcell selection, I perform a segue.  I have pasted my prepare for segue code below.  As it sits, the code seems to work fine.  However, when I move the line

```
currentSelectionPopOver = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
```

directly after the 
     [destList setDelegate:self];
statement, the if statements where I set my destList properties don't seem to take when the view is loaded.  Thoughts?   Just curious on the behavior.

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {



    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSelectionList"]) {

        //the destination view controller displays the data
        SelectionListController *destList = segue.destinationViewController;
        [destList setDelegate:self];


        //Set the type of selection list to show.
        if(tagThatRequestedSelectionList == TAG_OFFSET + STATE) {
            DLog()
            [destList setRequestType:STATES_LIST];
        }//end if.

        if(tagThatRequestedSelectionList == TAG_OFFSET + CITY) {
            DLog();
            [destList setRequestType:CITY_LIST];
        }//end if.

        //Setup a pointer to the popover controller so it can be dismissed.
        currentSelectionPopOver = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];    
     }
     }//end prepare.
```

Comment: What do you mean "don't seem to take".  Do they or don't they?  You have a debugger, step through and find the actual results

Comment: Okay, to give a bit more detail, here's what's going on.  When the currentSelecitonPopOver line precedes the series of IF statements that set the ReqestTypes,  the RequestType is correctly set according to the debugger.  However, when the segue is performed and the popOver is displayed, the requestType that was set is using the default value defined in the view being displayed as a popover, and not the one set in the code above.  Thus, the data displayed in the popover isn't what was requested in the prepareforsegue.

Comment: Do you check the type of `segue.destinationViewController`?